# How to avoid mouldy properties?

Tags: mold, materials, building

I've been wondering if there is any way to recognise materials/home designs which may mean the growth of mould in a house?

For normal properties, simply opening the window during a shower prevents most growth, yet I've previously lived in a property with mould growing in the bedroom - on the other side of the house to the bathroom. I know that possibly the blockage of fireplace might of meant that the ventilation wasn't there, but I feel like this may of been due to particular material or paint used on the exterior walls, which trapped moisture. I'd like to know for future reference if anyone is acknowledged in this field.

For clarification, I live in the UK.

Edit: To clarify, maybe this isn't really a question to home improvements, but I guess if I know the reason then I'd know how to deal with the issue and improve the home, if I'm not a tenant at such point, that is.

Answer (score 0):

Opening a window may just push bathroom moisture into the rest of the home, and if exterior humidity levels aren't low enough you're not accomplishing anything.

Air conditioning is the only reliable technique (along with adequate circulation), and even a dehumidifier may do the job.

Regarding materials, it's mostly in bathrooms and kitchens where non-porous wall finishes are important. Anywhere that steam can readily condense should be sealed.

Regarding design (architecture), solar exposure can help, but it mostly comes down to good HVAC implementation and, perhaps more importantly, good HVAC management. A smart thermostat with a regular fan cycle can do wonders during seasons when the HVAC system doesn't run often for heating or cooling.

Comment: Downvoter, care to comment? With what do you disagree?